# Displaying list content on visualforce page in a grid view

Tags: repeat, panelgrid

I have a list of a custom obj records containing data and image url. I am passing this list to an apex repeat on the visualforce page and want to display those records in a grid layout as shown in the image below. Three blocks on each row, each block showing the image on the left and the data on the right.

[image]

The part I have got working is showing the individual blocks with image and data. The part I need help with the showing these blocks as grid layout (as above).

Now I tried putting the apex repeat inside a panelGrid but it only filled one column with the data.

Here is the code I am using inside repeat

```
        <apex:repeat value="{!mylist}" var="obj">
            <apex:outputPanel id="blockViewPanel" styleClass="blockView">
                <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <apex:image url="{!obj.imageUrl}" styleClass="imageStyle"/>
                    <apex:panelGroup styleClass="dataStlye">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!obj.some_field1__c}"/><br/>
                        <apex:outputText value="{!obj.some_field2__c}"/><br/>
                    </apex:panelGroup>
                </apex:panelGrid>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:repeat>
```

Can you suggest any other solution to show a grid view on the vf page?
I am willing to explore CSS or JavaScript if native Visualforce solution does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? I've been playing around with this learning more about remote objects. This particular example is done with Bootstrap, and I'm quickly becoming a large fan as we are moving a lot of our internal stuff to Bootstrappy goodies.

If you create your Bootstrap container and row right outside your content area in your page `<div class="container-fluid"><div class="row"></div></div>`, this should be able to be accomplished by passing through `class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"`(or whichever column style works best for you) in that repeat using [HTML Passthrough](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm/). I havent personally tried to do this within a repeat with a panelgrid but I think it should work. If you go down the Bootstrap route, their [CSS help page](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) is amazing and the section on grids can help when figuring out the different classes for that grid layout you are looking for. [image]

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked. I am still having trouble displaying the image and the data side-by-side. The data moves under the image.

Comment: I'm curious how this looks. Can you post a screenshot of that? I'm wondering if you just need to try different grid styles.

Comment: I solved that issue yesterday. I had to change the way image and data are placed near each other.

Comment: <apex:outputPanel styleClass="container-fluid"><div class="row"><apex:repeat value=  var=> <apex:panelGrid styleClass="col-xs-6 col-md-4" columns="2"><apex:image/><apex:outputpanel>data</apex:outputpanel></apex:panelGrid></apex:repeat></div></apex:outputPanel>

Comment: Nice! Glad to know this works with the panelgrid inside a repeat!

Answer (score 0):

You could try [masonryjs](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html). It lets you use something similar to the Pinterest layout. Should not be terribly difficult to adapt to using for your use case.